# Was the directory in the Bradbury Building the real one in Demon with a Glass Hand?

Tags: real-location, the-outer-limits

We see a brief shot of a list of businesses that appear to be occupying the [Bradbury Building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradbury_Building) in which the Outer Limits episode
*The Time Mirror* was filmed.

I can see what looks like (all in the first column) a Magazine (distributor?). Also an attorney and maybe Steel companies (possibly more than one?)

**Is this the real business directory for the Bradbury or something created by makers of *The Outer Limits*?**

I believe in the "C" listings there is a Columbia Steel and Shafting Co. Now, this is a 60 year old episode and nothing shows up in LA but [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Columbia%20Steel%20and%20Shafting%20CO&oq=Columbia%20Steel%20and%20Shafting%20CO&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l3j33i15i22i29i30.454j0j7&client=ms-android-tef-gb-revc&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) shows a company with that exact name now in Atlanta.
This does indicate that possibly a real business directory was used.

I note that the first column's first few letters are cut off but using the remaining letters allowed me to guess Columbia.

**I have also found:** Continental News Service. [This was also apparently a real business at the time of the JFK assassination:](https://softpanorama.org/Skeptics/Political_skeptic/Two_party_system_as_poliarchy/Intelligence_agencies_influence/JFK_assasination/index.shtml)

If you search the above for "Goldstein" you can find an Ira Goldstein of the Continental News Service.

Googling on Ira Goldstein's name we see that he lived in Los Angeles at least when Bobby Kennedy was shot in 1968 and was both shot during the assassination and was employed by the Continental News.

Comment: If you think the best view is at a certain timestamp you should screencap it and include it here.  Don't make us do your work for you.

Comment: @David: There is no one best frame, you have to carefully move around 2:48.

Comment: That's not the Bradbury Building's directory. This ugly wrought-iron monstrosity is; https://live.staticflickr.com/912/41262040515_9853a12a7d_b.jpg

Comment: @Valorum: Why do you think that the directory in 1964 could not have been what we see in the episode? In fact, lots of wear and tear on directories. I do not know how you found the photo or if it is current -- it would be very cool if the "monstrosity" had shown up in the OL episode but I suspect the building as it became more famous, updated its appearance in many ways. The movie 500 Days of Summer shows a very upscale place.

Comment: @releseabe - The building is lovely. Their directory is not. You're right though, that might be a more recent addition, although wrought-iron isn't the sort of thing you ever really need to replace

Comment: @Valorum: In 1964 the building had yet to go through a series of many and extensive renovations. As the narrator indicates in the Demon episode, the building had fallen on hard times and certainly the dir u show us is a more expensive fixture. As far as ugly, I believe it must be in keeping with some architectural themes. I don't know why, but I really find this capture of the tenants (perhaps the only extant record) exciting esp. because it is in such a famous OL, written by Ellison.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it looks like indeed the Outer Limits episode Demon with a Glass Hand captured the real directory of the Bradbury Building in 1964. This may in fact be, partial though it is, perhaps the only record of which businesses were tenants of that famous building almost 60 years ago.

One might have thought they would have been careful to avoid photographing the directory -- lawsuits have been brought against movie makers for more trivial reasons than this.

That the Continental News Service had some other historical associations is interesting to me. This is the same news or "wire" service that Ben "Bugsy" Siegel took over apparently by poisoning its owner with mercury.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question asked in any meaningful way. On what basis are you asserting that this is the real directory for the building in 1964?

Comment: because real businesses in existence at the time have been shown as being listed.

Comment: All that shows is that some of the businesses listed were real names of businesses, not that they were tenants in the building.

Comment: Why not call the Columbia Steel and Shafting Co and ask them if they ever had a tenancy in that building?

Comment: i think it is very likely that it was the real directory. we can never know if, for example, they copied the real one but then altered it for some legal reason. but i doubt that.

Comment: That being the case, surely it would be better to leave the question unanswered in the hopes that someone with better research skills will be able to prove or disprove this, rather than posting an answer that seems to be pure guesswork without foundation.

Comment: @Valorum: i sure doubt anyone will improve on the "probably." Not very many names can even be figured out but two that I could look to be the names of actually businesses that existed. I do not think Continental exists today. I also doubt, having done things like contacted a pub mentioned in a book about the teens in NYC, that the current business would know about where it was located 60 years ago. They might have relocated from LA recently, which I guess would be interesting but Continental is good enough for me and it can never be proven short of someone involved in the making confirming it.